# Can't apply a Pantone color in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, pantone

I'm trying to change the color of a specific text applying a Pantone color. However after I clicked ok and click to check if the color was changed, the previous color is displayed instead of that Pantone I picked. I mean the Pantone color I tried to apply wasn't applied.

Note: the Pantone code I tried to use is 7471 C and next to the square sample appears an exclamation signal with the alt message "Out of gamut for printing". I have no idea what that is.

Will I have to pick another Pantone?

Comment: Google is your friend - there are countless videos and explanations that you could research before asking here. Its all about using Colour Channels - because you are adding a colour which is CMYK + 1 spot colour.

Comment: Sure, I always research about my doubts and I only posted here because I didn't figure out what was happening. What did you mean with "CMYK + 1 spot color"?

Comment: Yeah I understand your frustration at being new to a technique. This link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGgIB7PZWx0 - helps explain channels and separations. You must be working in CMYK colour mode, not RGB. The video gives an example of the technique to apply a gold finish but the method is the same. Hope it helps.

Comment: You can't have "pantone" in Photoshop unless you use multi-channels somehow. Your color will always be converted to your color mode. Either you learn how to use and save channels, or you simply use another software for your pantone (eg. Illustrator or Indesign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to set a Pantone color to a regular layer as you would any other color. Doing that won't get you an actual Pantone color (which needs to be printed with its own ink and therefor needs its own channel).

The "out of gamut" warning is because selecting a Pantone color as you did will simply convert the color to whichever color space you're working in, and many Pantone colors simply don't exist in CMYK or RGB.

If you're not sure on how to set up spot channels in Photoshop the answers in this previous Q&A may help you:

- [**Will layer effects affect how my Pantone design prints?**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74072/will-layer-effects-affect-how-my-pantone-design-prints/74082#74082)

You should also read through the Adobe help files on the issue:

- [**Photoshop Help / Print with spot colors**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/printing-spot-colors.html)

If you're not going to be printing with actual spot colors then don't worry about setting up extra channels. You can carry on as you were, but choose colors that don't give you the "out of gamut" warning or just live with the automatic conversion and be aware that you aren't getting actual Pantone colors.

Comment: Yes, your answer is exactly what I was looking for. It's true I didn't give a detailed explanation. So, what I actually didn't understand is about the right way to choose a pantone to use, for example, in a new brand I come to create and define the CMYK and RGB based on that pantone, I mean, choose all colors having that pantone as reference.

Comment: Yes, I had to pick another color and, actually, I think that I figured out the right Pantone color to use. What I needed is to have an official Pantone color to get based on, so it's what I did. I'm a great "RGB" user, but my experience with branding and printing is not so good. I count with you to help me with those stuff! Thanks.